# How to access a specific resw resource file

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

For a Windows 8 application in C#/XAML I need to access a specific ressource file. In WP7 I used resx file and now it seems that we need to use resw file. It's not a language resource file.
My file is called ConfigResources.resw, it just contains one key : "ConfigFile" and a value : a string.

How can I access it from my code? I tried this without any luck:

```
   var storedConfigFile = Application.Current.Resources["ConfigResources"];
```

Then how can I edit the value of the key inside from my code?

Thank you

Comment: Also have a look at http://blog.rsuter.com/?p=439

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Application-resources-and-cd0c6eaa) that shows the different ways to read the resources in WinRT apps (i.e. from resw files).

Comment: Thank you it really helped.I used MainResourceMap : var storedConfigFile = ResourceManager.Current.MainResourceMap.GetValue("ConfigResources/ConfigFile");

Answer (score 7):

I created a project on CodePlex recently called [ResW File Code Generator](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3ab88efd-1afb-4ff5-9faf-8825a282596a) that simplifies using localized resources in code in windows store app project. It's a custom tool that automatically generates and updates a helper class similar to what ResX files used in the full version of .NET

Comment: I am using same, but did you try using the .resw file in a background task?

Answer (score 5):

According to [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh694557.aspx), you need to use the `Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader` and  the `Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core` namespace provide interaction with resw files.

It should look something like this:

```
var loader = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader();
var text = loader.GetString("Farewell");
```

Alternately, if you're creating a cross-platform library you could also do it using the `System.Resources.ResourceManager`:

> Although the System.Resources.ResourceManager class is included in the
>   .NET for Windows Store apps, we do not recommend its use. Use
>   ResourceManager only in libraries that are developed as Portable Class
>   Library projects and that target multiple platforms.

Like this from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.resources.resourcemanager.aspx):

```
ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("Strings", typeof(Example).Assembly);
string timeString = rm.GetString("TimeHeader");
```

Comment: Yes I have seen this link the problem is how do I tell my Application that my ConfigResources.resw file is a ressource. var loader = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader(); doesn't work... and I don't use a cross-platform library.

Comment: @AstironNaviir Ah, I will have to see if I can find some time in the next couple days to play with it.  Work all day and classes all night today.  :-P

Comment: ResourceManager is also needed to display a string in a different language than the rest of the application, for a translation or a fixed language for example. ResourceLoader can only handle one active language (and a fallback).